# How can I convert response json string image into a displayable image

Tags: android, json, image, listview

My final year project requires me to develop a mobile application which fetches a number of Json values from a server. This is my first experience in android development but sure learned something’s and enjoyed the experience.

I have managed to develop the following.

1-a json parser class which fetches the value.

2-a class which displays these values.

3-a database where I store the json response.

However I'm one step away from completing my project, I cannot display the response string image address as real images (shame on me).
I need to do the following.

1- Parse the string path of the image and display the response as image.

I have spent most of my time trying to find the solution on the web, stack overflow. But no luck so far.
I need to do something like [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/11/android-full-app-part-6-customized-list.html) in order to display these images together with the text descriptions.

I have now reached the cross roads and my knowledge has been tested.Is what i'm trying to do here posible?.

Who can show me the way? ,to this outstanding platform.

Comment: Is it a *path* (such `/images/foobar.png`) to the image being sent, or is the image itself being encoded into the JSON? Could you post an example of the JSON you need to process?

Comment: I'm recieving the images as.                                                                 01-27 03:35:42.566: I/System.out(2387): http://media.rightmove.co.uk/3k/2265/35402969/2265_9897_IMG_00_0000_max_200x138.jpg

Comment: Sory not image path,i'm recieving the images in my app as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have the image `url` as a string, you can load and save the image using something like this:

```
try {   
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    File f = new File(filename);
    InputStream inputStream = new URL(url).openStream();
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);

    int readlen;
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    while ((readlen = inputStream.read(buf)) > 0)
        outputStream.write(buf, 0, readlen);

    outputStream.close();
    inputStream.close();
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename);

    return bitmap;
} catch (Exception e) {
    return null;
}
```

For saving, make sure you have appropriate permissions if you're going to save to sdcard.

if you just want to load the image (without saving):

```
    Bitmap bm = null;
    try {
        URL aURL = new URL(url);
        URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
        bis.close();
        is.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       Log.e(TAG, "Error getting bitmap", e);
   }
   return bm;
```

Just make sure you fetch the image in a separate thread or using `AsyncTask` or else you'll get ANRs!

Comment: Thanks for your response,I will implement this solution asap,this is what i want to convert as image which is returning a string.                                              "photoThumbnailUrl": "http: //media.rightmove.co.uk/31k/30471/29462938/30471_FLE100159_IMG_00_0002_max_200x138.jpg",

Comment: Thanks for your post,I have now find a good tutorial which solves my problems.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this ImageDownloader class from google. It´s works nice :)
Is an AsynkTask that handle the download and set the bitmap to an ImageView.

[ImageDownloader](http://code.google.com/p/googletv-video-player/source/browse/src/com/example/tv/videoplayer/ImageDownloader.java)

Usage:

```
private final ImageDownloader mDownload = new ImageDownloader();
mDownload.download("URL", imageView);
```